# navigateByUrl doesnt work inside a loading service using IONIC4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic loadingCtr in my project,here's the service :

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoadingServiceService {

  isLoading = false;
  spinner:any;
  constructor(
    public loadingController: LoadingController
  ) 
  { } 

  async showLoading(loadingId: string, loadingMessage: string = 'Loading...') {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      id: loadingId,
      message: loadingMessage,
      spinner: 'circles'
    });
    return await loading.present();
}

  async dismissLoader(loadingId: string) {
      return await this.loadingController.dismiss(null, null, loadingId).then(() => console.log('loading dismissed'));
  }


}
```

I'm calling this service, when I try to retrieve data from the server :

```
 submit(value: IUserRegister, isValid: boolean) {


 this.loading2.showLoading('ifOfLoading')

 this.authenticationService.register(value)
 .pipe(first())
 .subscribe(
   data => {
     if (data) {
       console.log('OK.');
       this.loading2.dismissLoader('ifOfLoading')
       this.router.navigateByUrl('/phone-dialog');

     } else {
       console.log('Problem');
       this.loading2.dismissLoader('ifOfLoading')

     }
   },
   err => {
    this.loading2.dismissLoader('ifOfLoading')
     console.log('ERROR :', err);

   } 
 );
 }
```

but My problem is, when this code execute, this line: this.router.navigateByUrl('/phone-dialog'); doesnt work, but when I remove the loading service it works , can any one tell me please what is the problem ?

Comment: remove ```/``` in front of url and try

Comment: its not about that, its bout this.loading2.showLoading('ifOfLoading') , because when I remove it, it works

Answer (score 0):

You use async and await function but why ?

Thank to the ionic LoadingController documentation, they don't put async function when creating Popover or Loading Controllers.

Can you give a try without ?

Hope this help :)

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, but I have to use ASYNC/AWAIT, it's mentioned in the DOC to work with  LoadingController   https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/loading

Comment: Seems like i saw the v3 version, but on the V4 i followed this: 
https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-adding-ion-loading-web-component-in-ionic-4-angular-application/#more-2198

And it works ^^